# Retrieve the web from Title programatically

Tags: web

How can i retrieve the web from its title programatically.

For example : I have url like `http://abc.sharepoint.com/Site1/SubSite1`

Now by using "SubSite1"(web Title) I need its web url

Comment: Using what? JS or C#?

Comment: And also what's your environment? SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in a site collection may be having more than one same titles of subsites
so here is a code to get web based on title matches in a site collection

```
using (SPSite spsite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Site.Url))
        {
            var allwebs = spsite.AllWebs.Cast<SPWeb>().Where(a => a.Title == "web title here");

            foreach (SPWeb item in allwebs)
            {
                //you can get web url from here which web title matches
                string url = item.Url; 
            }

        }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I noticed your answer as i was writing mine. I would suggest either creating the using block within your foreach, or use WebsInfo property to avoid thrashing SPWeb objects.  The SPWebCollection indexer does generate a new instance of the SPWeb object, thus you need to ensure its disposal.

Comment: URL `http://abc.sharepoint.com/Site1/SubSite1` seems your environment is SharePoint Online. In that case how this solution can work? @DRS

Comment: @AtishDipongkor the sample is for server-side object model only and can only work for On prem instances.  The code just needs to be refactored for managed CSOM equivalent or JSOM, depending on the requestor's needs.

Comment: @Roman we can use .WebsInfo property instead of Casting, it is better than casting

Comment: Yeah .... It has equivalent... But we need to know **OP**'s need at first.  OP did not bother to replay in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint platform differentiates the Site Title (web Title in your terms) and the Url Address.  When you navigate to Site Settings --> "Title, Description, and Logo", you can see both choices.

Your question lacks a bit of clarity. Are you attempting to get a reference Site instance object as in [SPWeb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb) for SSOM or [Web](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.aspx) for CSOM? If so, you need to iterate over a list of all Sites in the Site Collection and pick one that has a matching title or URL fragment.
Here is a sample using SSOM (server side object model) which can be used for SP2013 On-Premise.

```
using (var site = new SPSite("http://abc.sharepoint.com/Site1/SubSite1"))
{
  var resultSite = site
    .AllWebs
    .WebsInfo
    .FirstOrDefault(wi => wi.Title == "SubSite1 Title" || wi.ServerRelativeUrl == "/Site1/SubSite1");

  If (resultSite == null)
    return;

  using (var web = site.OpenWeb(resultSite.Id))
  {
    /// do your work here using SSOM
  }

  // Retrieving all matches
  var resultSites = site
    .AllWebs
    .WebsInfo
    .Where(wi => wi.Title == "SubSite1 Title" || wi.ServerRelativeUrl == "/Site1/SubSite1")
      .ToList();

  foreach (var spWebInfo in resultSites)
  {
    using (var web = site.OpenWeb(spWebInfo.Id))
    {
      /// do your work here using SSOM
    }
  }
}
```

If you were to clarify your request for "retrieving web from Title programmatically", then i am sure we can guide you further.

Based on the comment about the URL format, this does look like a SharePoint Online Tenant that you are asking about. The approach is similar but your code needs to be using CSOM or JSOM.

Comment: roman u used .FirstOrDefault Property, that means we can get only one result if there is multiple same web title in a site collection,

what will you do if there is more than one web title?

Comment: @HiteshChandegara Yes, you are correct, i am only taking the first match to the boolean expression.  I could use Where() with ToList() and then iterate over the list ... just like you are doing... this is just a sample. If requestor wants, i can modify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

URL `http://abc.sharepoint.com/Site1/SubSite1` seems to me that Environment is SharePoint Online.

For **SPO**, *CSOM* solution is needed.

Following is the REST API solution.

```
/_api/web/webs?$select=Url&$filter=Title eq 'SubSite1'
```

Make a GET request to the above *URL*, It will give you the Web *URL*.